# Deep Learning implementation in Tensorflow or Keras give drastic different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

***Context:** I'm using a fully convolutional network to perform image segmentation. Typically, the input is an RGB image `shape = [512, 256]` and the target is a 2 channels binary mask defining the annotated regions (2nd channel is the opposite of the fist channel).*

**Question:** I have the same CNN implementation using Tensorflow and Keras. But the Tensorflow model doesn't start learning. Actually, the `loss` even grows with the number of epochs! What is wrong in this Tensorflow implementation that prevents it from learning?

**Setup:** The dataset is split into 3 subsets: training (78%), testing (8%) and validation (14%) sets which are fed to the network by batches of 8 images. The graphs show the evolution of the `loss` for each subsets. The images show the `prediction` after 10 epoch for two different images.

---

**Tensorflow** implementation and results

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
x = inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, shape[1], shape[0], 3])
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, shape[1], shape[0], 2])

for d in range(4):
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=np.exp2(d+4), kernel_size=[3,3], strides=[1,1], padding="SAME", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, strides=[2,2], pool_size=[2,2], padding="SAME")
    
x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=2, kernel_size=[1,1])
logits = tf.image.resize_images(x, [shape[1], shape[0]], align_corners=True)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targets, logits=logits))
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def run(mode, x_batch, y_batch):
    if mode == 'TRAIN':
        return sess.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict={inputs: x_batch, targets: y_batch})
    else:
        return sess.run([loss, prediction], feed_dict={inputs: x_batch, targets: y_batch})
```

[image: Tensorflow loss evolution]
[image: Tensorflow prediction after 10 epochs]

---

**Keras** implementation and reslults

```
import keras as ke

ke.backend.clear_session()
x = inputs = ke.layers.Input(shape=[shape[1], shape[0], 3])

for d in range(4):
    x = ke.layers.Conv2D(int(np.exp2(d+4)), [3,3], padding="SAME", activation="relu")(x)
    x = ke.layers.MaxPool2D(padding="SAME")(x)

x = ke.layers.Conv2D(2, [1,1], padding="SAME")(x)
logits = ke.layers.Lambda(lambda x: ke.backend.tf.image.resize_images(x, [shape[1], shape[0]], align_corners=True))(x)
prediction = ke.layers.Activation('softmax')(logits)

model = ke.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=prediction)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy")

def run(mode, x_batch, y_batch):
    if mode == 'TRAIN':
        loss = model.train_on_batch(x=x_batch, y=y_batch)
        return loss, None
    else:
        loss = model.evaluate(x=x_batch, y=y_batch, batch_size=None, verbose=0)
        prediction = model.predict(x=x_batch, batch_size=None)
        return loss, prediction
```

[image: Keras loss evolution]
[image: Keras prediction after 10 epochs]

---

There must be a difference between the two but my understanding of the documentation lead me nowhere. I would be really interested to know where the difference lies. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont understand what those plots are. But the only discrepancy I find between your 2 versions is the TF one uses same padding for pooling layers which is unusual and probably the source of error.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't make the difference. I completed the question with more details, and gave results with the "same" padding in both TF and K.

Comment: Could you try using `tf.reduce_sum` for the cost?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was in the Keras implementation of [`softmax`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py) where they subtract an unexpected `max`:

```
def softmax(x, axis=-1):
    # when x is a 2 dimensional tensor
    e = K.exp(x - K.max(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True))
    s = K.sum(e, axis=axis, keepdims=True)
    return e / s
```

---

Here is the Tensorflow implementation updated with the `max` hack and the good results associated

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
x = inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, shape[1], shape[0], 3])
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, shape[1], shape[0], 2])

for d in range(4):
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=np.exp2(d+4), kernel_size=[3,3], strides=[1,1], padding="SAME", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, strides=[2,2], pool_size=[2,2], padding="SAME")

x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=2, kernel_size=[1,1])
logits = tf.image.resize_images(x, [shape[1], shape[0]], align_corners=True)
# The misterious hack took from Keras
logits = logits - tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_max(logits, axis=-1), -1)
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=targets, logits=logits))
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def run(mode, x_batch, y_batch):
    if mode == 'TRAIN':
        return sess.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict={inputs: x_batch, targets: y_batch})
    else:
        return sess.run([loss, prediction], feed_dict={inputs: x_batch, targets: y_batch})
```

[image: Tensorflow loss evolution]
[image: Tensorflow predictions after 10 epochs]

Huge thanks to Simon for pointing this out on the `Keras` implementation :-)